# How to match exact number of whitespaces when \s doesnt work in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have the below patterns to match in my file in Linux and I would prefer to use awk for this :

```
/*   1 */
/*  65 */
/* 235 */
/*9999 */
```

While I already tried the below code, it looks like `\s` is not working on my server. The pattern will always be a total of 9 characters.

```
\/\*[\w\d\s]{5}\*\/
```

I know there is a way around this using `[[:space:]]`, but I'm unable to figure out how exactly it works.
I would ideally like to also understand how to match say, 3 spaces along with digits and characters, using  the *POSIX* method. Example : `[:space:]{3}`

Comment: What version of awk are you using and what distro is your server?

Comment: Why don't you just try `[ ]{2,}`? This should select two or more spaces.

Comment: You haven't told us what you think `\w`, `\d`, or `\<` should mean. It's not useful to say `how can I implement "foobar" in awk` without telling us what `"foobar"` means to you.

Comment: @ryekayo : I'm using SLES11

Comment: @EdMorton: Sorry, I meant `\w` (words) `\d` (digits) `\s` (whitespaces) in the same example which i mentioned with the similar method that i tried. Only using posix.

Comment: None of those abbreviations are posix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '/\/\*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*\*\//' file
/*   1 */
/*  65 */
/* 235 */
/*9999 */

$ awk '/\/\*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{3}[[:space:]]*\*\//' file
/* 235 */

$ awk '/\/\*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{3,}[[:space:]]*\*\//' file
/* 235 */
/*9999 */
```

Comment: Thanks. The only solution that worked for me was the first one. 
`awk '/\/\*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*\*\//' file`
For some reason the `{m,n}` doesnt seem to work. I'm on SLES11.

Comment: I've no idea what `SLES11` is. If your awk doesn't handle range expressions than you seriously need to get a new awk, preferably gawk 4.*.

Comment: SLES is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. And probably like you guessed the version of gawk could be an issue here. It shows GNU Awk 3.1.6.

Comment: That is an extremely old of version of gawk, you are missing a ton of incredibly useful functionality, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History. With the version you have you need to add the `--re-interval` option to enable RE intervals.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (if I got you correctly):

```
awk '/\/\*[[:alnum:][:space:]]{5}\*\//' file.txt
```